# Hubspot Imports: Temporarily increase my daily API call limit

Tags: api, limits

I'd like to import all of my apto contacts into Hubspot. This would require 18k API calls, and I have a limit of 15k.

Is there a way to request a temporary increase on the limit on my account so I can perform this import?

I tried calling salesforce but couldn't get a human being. Maybe there's a form for this somewhere on their website?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: If you are a SalesForce partner you can raise a case with them on the [partner portal](https://partners.salesforce.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open a case in their help center and ask them to temporarily increase your limit (with an explanation of why).

Steps:

1) Log in to salesforce, and click the "help and training" link in the upper right corner of your page. OR navigate to help.salesforce.com

2) Scroll to the footer, and click the "Submit a Case" button.

3) Submit a case asking for salesforce to temporarily increase your limit. I've read that this is something they do if you have a good reason for it. Will post back later with results.

Edit: This worked. They increased my limit per my request. Took them ~8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I know that they do offer API limit increases for a fee. They might make a one-time exception for you.

The best way to reach a live person at Salesforce is to [open a case](https://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport). They're very good about calling you back. Even when I've submitted cases with medium priority, I've received a call back within 24 hours.

Comment: Temporary increases are free. Permanent increases are what they charge for. In general, usage limits can be temporarily extended in a per case basis, such as sending emails or using API calls. Such increases must be reasonable and very short term, usually just a few days. You Vann also request temporary features, such as API or monthly data export for professional edition, for migration purposes

Comment: Good to know. I've never had cause to ask them for a temp increase, so I didn't want to speak out of line. I have found Salesforce to be quite amenable when a customer makes a reasonable request.

Answer (score 1):

You could also build a Salesforce report and export all your Contacts to a CSV. Then use the Import from File function in HubSpot to import all of your contacts from the CSV that you recently exported from Salesforce. This wouldn't require any API calls.